# Is it necessary to filter the outer query in a join?

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

Query:

```
SELECT i1.* 
FROM   (SELECT store_id, 
               transaction_fid 
        FROM   transactions i 
               inner join (SELECT prod_id 
                           FROM   products 
                           WHERE  category = '802') p 
                       ON i.prod_id = p.prod_id 
        WHERE  i.date_id = '10-SEP-16') i1 
       inner join transactions i2 
               ON i1.store_id = i2.store_id 
                  AND i1.transaction_fid = i2.transaction_fid
```

In the above query, I'm trying to get transactions that have items that belong to the `category` '802'

The inner query matches each line from `transactions` where `prod_id` is a `prod_id` of an item in `category` 802.

The outer query then takes the `store_id` and `transaction_fid` and joins them back to the transaction table to get all other items in the matched transactions.

My question is - do i need to filter the outer query to be in the same date range as the inner query, or does it not matter in terms of efficiency/how long the query takes to run?

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I believe there is a better way to do this - I think you've gotten overly complicated - why not just inner join transactions with item on the item_id and then limit the category to 802 - if you only need the transaction store you can use distinct to make sure you don't get all the transactions - though - i can't fully be sure without seeing your table set up - usually when you are creating such a thing you have an order table - and item table and a cross join table of order_items

Comment: i want everything else in the transaction that a specific item was bought in, so i can find out if there are any correlations between this item being purchased and other items being purchased with it

if i just joined transactions to items for category 802 i would only get records for items that are in the category. i want everything else that was bought with that item.

Comment: There's an easier way to write your subquery even then - again - without clarity of you DDL i can't be sure

Answer (score 2):

based on your table names and join types the query should something like :

```
select i1.store_id,i1.transaction_fid
from  transactions i1
inner join products p
on i1.prod_id = p.prod_id 
where p.category = '802'
and i1.date_id = '10-SEP-16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this?

```
SELECT tr.*
FROM transactions AS tr
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.prod_id=tr.prod_id
WHERE i.date_id = {d'2016-09-10'}
  AND pr.category='802' --really string value? If int-value better as naked number
```

**Btw: You really should avoid date/time value as culture depending string literals!**